# Multi-field searches in Access with blank fields

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in access (simplified) with fields of sex, first name, last name, and phone number.

```
Sex     First    Last     Phone
F       Alice    Smith
M       Bob               111-111-1111
F                Smithe    111-111-1112
M       Charlie  Smith     
F       Eve      Drop      111-111-1113
```

I have created a form along with a query to search for the records, using the criteria of

```
Is Null Or Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![Criteria] & "*"
```

where Search is the name of my form, and Criteria is the name of the individual entries on my form.

Right now, if I search for Sex F and the last name Smith, and leave the first and last name fields blank, I want to be able to see the records for "Alice Smith" and "Smithe". But instead, I only get the record of "Alice Smith". Furthermore, if I search for Sex F and phone number 111, I get results for Alice, Smithe, and Eve. Similarly, if I just search for phone number alone, I will get all five records.

I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't tell what it is. Based on the conditional logic of or, the results should be either Null or 111 (and similar for the other fields), so I guess it is behaving as expected. I've tried xor however, and I get the same result (and even if it does work the way I'm thinking it would, it would seem bad since a blank entry would be interpreted as null instead of "search every entry". I've tried using iif, which should be the correct way to do this, but it appears to not work when placed in the criteria field. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

`Null` is the special value (with the meaning `not-known`) and it is *NOT* the same as a *blank text field*, which has the value `""` (empty string).

So adjust your criteria to accept the value `""`.

Comment: Doesn't `Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![Criteria] & "*"` cover `""`?
In any case, I still appear to have the same problem after substituting `Is Null` with `""`.

Comment: Scratch that:

If I search for `Smith` in the last name field, for example, I would now have the records for Alice and Charlie, but I won't have the record for Smith, which is the issue that I had before.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-field search use criteria for each field like this:

```
WHERE    
([Sex] Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![CriteriaSex] & "*" 
    OR Nz([Forms]![Search]![CriteriaSex],"")="")
AND ([First] Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![CriteriaFirst] & "*" 
    OR Nz([Forms]![Search]![CriteriaLast],"")="")
AND ([Last] Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![CriteriaLast] & "*" 
    OR Nz([Forms]![Search]![CriteriaLast],"")="")
AND ([Phone] Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![CriteriaPhone] & "*" 
    OR Nz([Forms]![Search]![CriteriaPhone],"")="")
```

In this case every condition will be TRUE if corresponding criteria field is empty.

Comment: What are `MySearchField1` and `MySearchField2`? (I'm pretty new to access. I have been using `Criteria` as placeholders for the field names, so I don't see how the above two differ from `Criteria`.

Would this also mean that if I have  eight fields, I would need 7 `And`s?

Comment: I edited the answer, it should be more clear now. `MySearchField*` were table field names, `Criteria*` - textbox controls names

Comment: I'll attempt this in a bit and see. Just to be clear, I will be putting this in SQL view? I've been using the design view for a while, but SQL view honestly looks simpler.

Comment: Yes, definitely SQL view is much simpler for such kind conditions. If you convert this to design view, it will look almost unreadable, especially if you have another conditions

Answer (score 0):

Another way to build this query would be to build a string based upon which fields are populated.

```
q = "SELECT * FROM table "
w = ""
IF(nz([Forms]![Search]![Criteria1],"")<> "") THEN
     w = "WHERE [table]![field] like '*" & [Forms]![Search]![Criteria1] & "*'"
END IF
IF(nz([Forms]![Search]![Criteria2],"")<> "") THEN
     IF (w="") THEN 
          w=" WHERE "
     ELSE 
          w=w & " AND "
     END
     w = w & " [table]![field] like '*" & [Forms]![Search]![Criteria2] & "*'"
END IF
IF(nz([Forms]![Search]![Criteria3],"")<> "") THEN
     IF (w="") THEN 
          w=" WHERE "
     ELSE 
          w=w & " AND "
     END
     w = w & " [table]![field] like '*" & [Forms]![Search]![Criteria3] & "*'"
END IF
q = q & w
```